# Lazyload not working on Turbolinks page refresh (but works on normal page refresh)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, turbolinks, jquery-lazyload

I'm trying to implement Lazyloading of images in my RoR web app, which uses Turbolinks.

I've implemented this gem: https://github.com/jassa/lazyload-rails

It works perfectly as intended if I do a "hard" refresh of the site (which triggers document.ready), but it does not load if the page is loaded by Turbolinks.

I tried changing this code in the jquery.lazyload.js file (line 163):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      alert("Loaded");
        update();
    });
```

to

```
    $(document).on('turbolinks:load', function () {
      alert("Loaded");
        update();
    });
```

But I don't get any alerts in the browser when I do a Turbolinks page load, which makes me believe the lazyload script itself doesn't even get triggered when the page is loaded using Turbolinks.

This is my application.js

```
//= require jquery2
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require libs/dropzone.js
//= require Chart.bundle
//= require chartkick
//= require font_awesome5
//= require jquery.lazyload
//= require_tree .

$("img").lazyload();
```

And this is how I call lazyload on the image

```
<%= image_tag f.image, lazy: true %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution myself.

The application.js file only gets called upon a hard refresh, so when the page is loaded via Turbolinks it did not call the $("img").lazyload() function. Solved it by adding this line to the header in the application.html.erb file:

```
<script>
  $(document).on('turbolinks:load', function () {
    $("img").lazyload();
  });
  $('document').ready(function(){
    $("img").lazyload();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: In the end, I ended up just disabling Turbolinks completely as even this solution was too unstable when performing device testing - sometimes it would just not load at all completely. When I removed the Turbolinks gem completely everything worked perfectly.